# Show past date with disable in jquery ui datepicker

Tags: jquery, datepicker

I need to show the datepicker show the previous dates but not the selectable, Because in edit page i have to show the previously selected date so i want to show the date but not selectable.

Here i am using this code

```
$( "#editFrom" ).datepicker({  
    dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
    numberOfMonths: 2,
    autoclose: true,
    minDate:0,
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to set all days selection close

```
$( "#editFrom" ).datepicker({  
    dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
    numberOfMonths: 2,
    autoclose: true,
    minDate:0,
    beforeShowDay: function highlightDays(date) {
           return[false,"closed"]
    }
});
```